# Many to many relation in NHibernate (Fluent NHibernate) creating unexpected records in database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, hibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using Fluent NHibernate for many to many relation between Store and Product. I am not posting the entities since it is irrelevant. These are my mappings

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
using FluentNHibernateSample.Domain;

namespace FluentNHibernateSample.Mappings
{
    public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
    {
        public ProductMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.Name);
            Map(x => x.Price);
            HasManyToMany(x => x.Stores).Cascade.All().
                Table("StoreProduct").ParentKeyColumn("ProductId")
                .ChildKeyColumn("StoreId");
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
using FluentNHibernateSample.Domain;

namespace FluentNHibernateSample.Mappings
{
    public class StoreMap : ClassMap<Store>
    {
        public StoreMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.Name);
            HasMany(x => x.Staff).KeyColumn("StoreId").Cascade.All();
            HasManyToMany(x => x.Products).Cascade.All().
                Table("StoreProduct").
                ParentKeyColumn("StoreId").ChildKeyColumn("ProductId");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my sample code which tries to insert records in database:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NHibernate;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db;
using FluentNHibernateSample.Domain;

namespace FluentNHibernateSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ISessionFactory sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();

            using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
            {
                session.Transaction.Begin();

                Store store = new Store();
                store.Name = "Emall";

                Product product = new Product();
                product.Name = "Emall Item 1";
                product.Price = 12.5;

                //Sample code below

                session.Save(store);

                session.Transaction.Commit();

                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }

        private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
        {
            return Fluently.Configure().
                    Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.
                        ConnectionString( m => m.FromConnectionStringWithKey(System.Environment.MachineName))).
                    Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>()).
                        BuildSessionFactory();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample code:

```
            //option 1 ==> doesn't work
            product.Stores.Add(store);

            //option 2 ==> works
            store.Products.Add(product);

            //option 3 ==> creates 2 entries in Junction table
            product.Stores.Add(store);
            store.Products.Add(product);
```

Why does the 2nd option work whereas 1st one doesn't? I understand this is happening because I am adding store to product and saving store. But shouldn't the 1st option also work because of object tracking? Further the 3rd option totally surprises me by creating 2 records in the junction table. How can I solve this issue? Is there anything wrong in mapping classes?

Answer (score 1):

one side of the bi directional manytomany has to be the one which is responsible for the association meaning is resposible to insert the linking-records. The nonresponsible side has to say `.Inverse()` to tell NH that the other side is responsible.

```
// for example
HasManyToMany(x => x.Products).Inverse()
```

Update: to be consistent you always need to use `option 3`, otherwise its wired up in db but not inmemory which leads to subtle bugs

```
// in Store
public virtual void Add(Product product)
{
    if(!Products.Contains(product))
    {
        Products.Add(product);
        product.Add(this);
    }
}

// in Product
public virtual void Add(Store store)
{
    if(!Stores.Contains(store))
    {
        Stores.Add(store);
        store.Add(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: After doing that it still doesn't work. I did ` HasManyToMany(x => x.Stores).Inverse()`.Then I tried my 1st option and I can see record in store but neither in product table nor in the junction table. I guess I have to always remember which is the "responsible" side and always use that while inserting.